# Entity framework to CSV float values

Tags: c#, entity-framework, csv

I'm trying to write an object to csv, the thing is that my objects have float valure for exemple (14,9) i want to change them to (14.9) so it won't cause any problem with the csv format

```
string csv = "";
using (var ctx = new NBAEntities2())
{
    var studentList = ctx.TotalStat.SqlQuery("Select * from TotalStat where IDPlayer<5")
                                   .ToList<TotalStat>();

    List<object> mycollection = new List<object>();
    string type = "";
    foreach (var item in studentList)
    {
        type = item.GetType().ToString();
        mycollection.Add(item);
    }

    string iteem = mycollection.First().ToString();

    IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> props = mycollection.First().GetType().GetProperties();

    //header 
    List<string> test = new List<string>();

    csv += String.Join(",", props.Select(prop => prop.Name)) + "\r\n";

    //rows
    foreach (var entityObject in mycollection)
    {
        csv += String.Join(",", props.Select(
            prop => (prop.GetValue(entityObject, null) ?? "?").ToString()
        ))
        + "\r\n";
    }
}

File.WriteAllText("D:/Test.csv", csv.ToString());
```

Comment: What is your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably in your case the simplest way to do it is to change the current thread culture then restore it.

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
```

You can also specify a format provider in
`(prop.GetValue(entityObject, null) ?? "?").ToString()`
but in this case you probably need to check if `prop.GetValue(entityObject, null)` is `IFormattable` (or if is a single or a double) then apply the `ToString` specifying the `InvariantCulture`.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, forgot to update this post, it's by changing the thread culture

```
 System.Globalization.CultureInfo customCulture = (System.Globalization.CultureInfo)System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Clone();
                customCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";

                System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = customCulture;
```